# how to sum subsets from one column of csv and write it in python (sum lines of data for each hour into day data / 8000+lines into 365)

Tags: python, csv

I am new to Python and using it for studies. I need to take bunch of files (example of file bellow, first 49 lines) make them shorter, because i want to merge two **csv** files and one has data for each Day Of Year once and another gives similar data but rows are for each hour (24 times per day, 365 days). I tried many things from SO, but seems my lack of knowledge prevents me from combining several commands successfully (or data types?).

My code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('HourlySurfaceEmissions.csv', header=0)
i = data['Total CH4 oxidized in Cover (g/m2/day)'].count()
g = 0
for h in range (i):
    for j in range (24):
        g=g+data.iloc[j,3]
        l=data.iloc[j,0]
        if j==24:
            data.append(g)
```

Also tried like this:

```
test_list=pd.read_csv("HourlySurfaceEmissions.csv")
res = [ sum(test_list[x : x + 24])  
       for x in range(0, len(test_list), 24)]
```

Example of first 49 lines (header and 2x24hours=2days/DOY) bellow:

```
DOY,Surface emission with oxidation (g/m2/day),Surface emissions without oxidation(g/m2/day),Total CH4 oxidized in Cover (g/m2/day)
0.006944444444444444,0.0,0.009640456293691613,-11.050865124798417
0.048611111111111105,0.0,0.00965194619432311,-11.076678943428105
0.09027777777777778,0.0,0.009670805122605135,-11.109966479947506
0.1319444444444444,0.0,0.00968945315690706,-11.14340896370453
0.17361111111111105,0.0,0.009705649616079596,-11.174967827473246
0.2152777777777778,0.0,0.009717268095524405,-11.203014257215516
0.25694444444444453,0.0,0.009722552966172965,-11.225477458228605
0.29861111111111127,0.0,0.009724124256746654,-11.24121710215802
0.34027777777777796,0.0,0.009721011637697558,-11.249792693463574
0.3819444444444445,0.0,0.009710336075834235,-11.25189835695853
0.423611111111111,0.0,0.009693294362800385,-11.24758026308563
0.4652777777777775,0.0,0.009671063350622646,-11.236969394828964
0.5069444444444441,0.0,0.009645088049109159,-11.220564696750134
0.5486111111111106,0.0,0.009617185341758622,-11.199264953875893
0.5902777777777771,0.0,0.009589224265734546,-11.174114980089575
0.6319444444444436,0.0,0.009563049606687848,-11.146251643323737
0.6736111111111102,0.0,0.009540407718328061,-11.116685043446322
0.7152777777777771,0.0,0.009523258672310022,-11.08680098084354
0.7569444444444441,0.0,0.009512384905543625,-11.057545055124129
0.798611111111111,0.0,0.009508670518647058,-11.029278794405451
0.840277777777778,0.0,0.009512661727449441,-11.002881748121855
0.881944444444445,0.0,0.00952351344623122,-10.97773709236616
0.9236111111111119,0.0,0.00954086056094301,-10.953696342508493
0.9652777777777789,0.0,0.009563077061452775,-10.930675397066185
1.0069444444444458,0.0,0.009589258645691398,-10.908521124174303
1.0486111111111127,0.0,0.009612332930178632,-10.888018955865018
1.0902777777777797,0.0,0.009633980489113781,-10.865257726415996
1.1319444444444466,0.0,0.00965520708644411,-10.840145827335935
1.1736111111111136,0.0,0.00967502739071609,-10.81119149049327
1.2152777777777806,0.0,0.009688774630252922,-10.778337840301566
1.2569444444444475,0.0,0.00969569215820134,-10.74019647299494
1.2986111111111145,0.0,0.00969592668116943,-10.696893492706971
1.3402777777777812,0.0,0.00968931970890368,-10.648206749669301
1.3819444444444473,0.0,0.00967607201768951,-10.594140416915286
1.4236111111111134,0.0,0.009656874404941456,-10.535050797245228
1.4652777777777795,0.0,0.009632855346341005,-10.471615970651886
1.5069444444444455,0.0,0.009605489625697603,-10.404775922333677
1.5486111111111116,0.0,0.009576486960140714,-10.33565555817896
1.5902777777777777,0.0,0.00954766999289027,-10.265477645235027
1.6319444444444438,0.0,0.00952105413826517,-10.195657825444055
1.6736111111111098,0.0,0.009497910541739782,-10.126978222694369
1.715277777777776,0.0,0.009480190056013282,-10.060470694066083
1.756944444444442,0.0,0.009469075701263357,-9.997509432663001
1.798611111111108,0.0,0.009464933381231574,-9.938139854922564
1.8402777777777741,0.0,0.009468689077078025,-9.883065879435845
1.8819444444444402,0.0,0.009479602575435297,-9.831948683825386
1.9236111111111063,0.0,0.009497056058672237,-9.784327743717228
1.9652777777777724,0.0,0.009520302331279774,-9.739751373553043
```

Result expected:

```
1,0.0,0.228,-9.739,264.456
2,0.0,0.227,-9.539,264.356
3,0.0,0.229,-9.839,264.256
```

I made up these, but roughly it's what should i get.
Please help.

Comment: can you format your data into a reproducible format, i.e make it possible for us to copy into our IDE. also can you elaborate on what you mean when you say, _make the data shorter_

Comment: what do You mean reproducible? attach as a file somehow? 
"data shorter" - there are 8000+ rows in a file because 365 days in a year and times 24 hours per day, i need 365 rows only, so sum rows 1-24 and result saves as row 1 and sum rows 25-47 and write answer in a row 2... and so on

Comment: what logic are you trying to do here, do you want to sum along the rows by each unique DOY?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you just want to sum every 24 rows so the following code will produce the desired result

```
slim = df.groupby(df.index // 24).sum()

print(slim)

         DOY  ...  Total CH4 oxidized in Cover (g/m2/day)
0  11.666667  ...                             -267.107334
1  35.666667  ...                             -249.341336
```

We can see that the results are as expected.

```
slim.iloc[0]

DOY                                               11.666667
Surface emission with oxidation (g/m2/day)         0.000000
Surface emissions without oxidation(g/m2/day)      0.230957
Total CH4 oxidized in Cover (g/m2/day)          -267.107334
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Lastly let's change the index as well, as shown in your OP.

```
slim.index = range(1, len(slim) + 1)

         DOY  ...  Total CH4 oxidized in Cover (g/m2/day)
1  11.666667  ...                             -267.107334
2  35.666667  ...                             -249.341336
```

Comment: Thank You! I will continue from this.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [3]: data.head(4)                                                                                                                                                        
Out[3]:
        DOY  Surface emission with oxidation (g/m2/day)  Surface emissions without oxidation(g/m2/day)  Total CH4 oxidized in Cover (g/m2/day)
0  0.006944                                         0.0                                       0.009640                              -11.050865
1  0.048611                                         0.0                                       0.009652                              -11.076679
2  0.090278                                         0.0                                       0.009671                              -11.109966
3  0.131944                                         0.0                                       0.009689                              -11.143409
4  0.173611                                         0.0                                       0.009706                              -11.174968

In [4]: data.index = data.index.values.astype('timedelta64[h]')
In [5]: data.resample('D').sum()
Out [5]: 
              DOY  Surface emission with oxidation (g/m2/day)  Surface emissions without oxidation(g/m2/day)  Total CH4 oxidized in Cover (g/m2/day)
0 days  11.666667                                         0.0                                       0.230957                             -267.107334
1 days  35.666667                                         0.0                                       0.230030                             -249.341336
```

Comment: Thank You for Your contribution! It solves my problem.

Comment: @IgnasDaugėla you're welcome. Usually the one that solves it is the accepted answer, but I think his code does the same thing essentially

Comment: Changing it to time frame creates me a new problem of a appending columns to other csv files with series I suppose? And I didn't wanted to disturb others at the moment.

Comment: New problem? no, as you can see yourself indexes can be safely manipulated. Since what you are doing is resampling data based on time, regardless of doing it in pandas or R or any other statistic tools, you need to make the sum based on time unit. Example https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resample-and-aggregate-data-in-timetable.html